# TexShop integration with Dropbox problem

Tags: texshop, dropbox

I store my `.tex` files in Dropbox and use a TexShop at mac in my office and WinEdt at PC at home for editing them. I leave my `.tex` files open (but saved) on both computers. When I come home and make a `.tex` file window active on my WinEdt, it informs me that if the file has changed in Dropbox and loads the most current version. How can I make TexShop do the same?

Sometimes I make significant edits in TexShop and only when I try to save them TexShop informs me that I am working on an old version of the file.

Admittedly, it is a small issue, since I can always close and reopen a file before I start working on it, to make sure that I work on the latest version, but it would be nice not to have to do it, since it is easy to forget about it.